# Storing data from database in a 1d array not 2d

Tags: php, arrays

I want to store a column of my database table in an array so I can compare it with an array I have. I am selecting only one column from the table and I am storing all the rows. I've managed to do so but in a 2d array but when comparing the 2d array to my 1d array i get an error. So please help me to convert it into a 1d array or from the begining if I can store the data in a 1d array.

```
    $array = array();
$serviceId = "SELECT service_id FROM servicesorders WHERE order_id = '$orderId'";
$resultId = mysqli_query($connection, $serviceId) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
while ($serviceIdfinal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultId)) {
$array[] = $serviceIdfinal; //the array I used to store the data 
}
var_dump($array);

$isCheckedstring = $_POST['show'];
$isCheckedarray = str_split($isCheckedstring, 4); // the array I want to compare the stored data with
var_dump($isCheckedarray);
```

the var_dump of the two arrays are as follows:

```
array( 
    [0]=> array(
        ["service_id"]=> "1"
    )
    [1]=> array(
        ["service_id"]=> "7"
    )
    [2]=> array( 
        ["service_id"]=> "11" 
    ) 
)
```

And

```
array(
    [0]=>"0011"
    [1]=>"0012"
)
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says **[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**. Learn about [Prepared Statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even **[escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)** is not safe!

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton haven't seen little booby in a long time

Comment: have you tryed to use fetch_all http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php, and something like $result_array = array_values($fetched_all_array); ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: what is the reason to compare in php? it can be better to compare in sql, can't it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition

Comment: I have a list of services that is generated by the database when a user needs to edit their chosen services in an order I compare the new services chosen with the old ones to update the order database table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` so you need to fetch the associative column.

You need to change

```
while ($serviceIdfinal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultId)) {
    $array[] = $serviceIdfinal; //the array I used to store the data 
}
```

to

```
while ($serviceIdfinal = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultId)) {
    $array[] = $serviceIdfinal['service_id']; //the array I used to store the data 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your database returns an array, it's returning an array of rows, each of which is an associative array.  It doesn't matter that each row has one element within it, it's still an array of arrays.

You're going to have to convert the `$array` from one form to another with a foreach loop:

```
$newArray = [];
foreach($array as $row) {
    // This line here is where you'll do any needed string modifications
    // such as padding with leading zeroes, etc.
    $newArray[] = $row["service_id"]; 
}
var_dump($newArray)
```

This should net you:

```
array( 
    [0]=> "1",
    [1]=> "7",
    [2]=> "11"
)
```

EDIT: Or you should do it in the while loop you're already using when you're fetching it, as Milan pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417504/4385613).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use PDO instead of mysqli.

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
$sql = $conn->query("your query");
$sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That's it :)

Comment: PDO still returns an array of rows, and each row is an array.  It doesn't solve the issue.